# Run code after promise resolves at other code position

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, mean

i know the title is kind of confusing but i did not knwo how to describe my problem more precisely - sorry for that.

So to be more precise, i am new to javascript and i am having a project with MEAN Stack architecture. Within my code i am updating a document of my "Question" model and some place in the code. The code which follows has to run independently of whether the document has already been saved or not - except the last line of the method, where i am sending a response back to my angular client via socket. Additionally, as you may see, a whole array of questions gets updated question by question so it can be hardly done with a simple .then because somehow i must check if the whole array of questions has already been saved and then execute my last command.

To illustrate the problem, here some code snippets.

```
              room.connections.forEach(connection => {
                Question.find({room: room.title}).then(questions => {
                  questions.forEach(question => {
                    if (question.answers.length !== 2) {
                      question.answers.push({email: connection.userId, own: "", guess: ""});
                      question.save(); // This is the promise to check for later on in code 

                    }
                  })
                });
              });
```

So, after this code block other code lines are following which, as i said, have to run independently of whether the Question has already been updated or not. 
But as the last line of my method i have the following statement which send back a response to indicate that the clients can load the quiz game - this command should then just be executed as soon as the questions have been saved on the DB:

```
      } else{
              // GameReady is sent and both users open the Game Page
              io.of('/game').in(room.title).emit('GameReady', true); // THIS IS THE COMMAND I AM TALKING ABOUT 
              ack(false);
     }
```

As i said, this is my first javascript project, and i know that promises are used for this kind of stuff, but normally i could use questions.save().then(...."here the rest of the code") - but in my case the code "in between" should be executed already before and it is a save within a forEach which i rally do not knwo how i could handle this.

So, hope you understood my problem and thanks a lot for your appreciated help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, I think you want [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

If `question.save()` returns a promise, and you want to run code after all questions have finished saving, then:

```
Question.find({ room: room.title }).then(questions => {
  Promise.all(
    // Use a map here so each question generates a promise.
    // Resulting in an array of promises.
    questions.map(question => {
      if (question.answers.length !== 2) {
        question.answers.push({ email: connection.userId, own: "", guess: "" })
        return question.save() // return the promise so Promise.all can wait for it.
      }
    }),
  ).then(() => {
    // All questions have been saved. Do the next thing.
    io.of("/game")
      .in(room.title)
      .emit("GameReady", true)
    ack(false)
  })
})
```

Comment: omg, this really worked out! I do not fully understand your code yet, but i guess i will as soon as i am checking the whole description of promise.all and map. Before, i tried to make a method which should handle the inserts, and just return a resolved promise as soon as ALL inserts/saves are finished - unfortunately this did not work out - i did something like insertQuestions(room).then(()  => { socket.emit.....});  - where "insertQuestions" returns the promise - but then got an error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" - anyway thanks a lot

Comment: Sounds like your `insertQuestions()` function does not return a promise then. Feel free to post a new question about that if you're still confused. In the meantime, don't forget to upvote and accept answers that solved helped you.

Comment: I could not upvote because i do mot have enough credits, but i accepted your answer as the correct one. Thanks again